# Обход блокировки сайта извне

Tags: vpn, блокировки

Всем привет. Владею одним ресурсом. Его заблокировали на територии государства. Т.Е. если включить VPN то сайт открывается, без VPN не открывается. Какие способы решения есть обхода этой системы? Первый раз с таким столкнулся, понятия не имею как быть. У сайта хорошие позиции в SEO, перекидывал пару раз домен, но периодически блокируют

Comment: Уточни причины ограничения доступа к твоей площадке.

Comment: @edem Не могу сказать, государство заблочило

Comment: Если речь про государство Россия, то можешь посмотреть причины здесь https://eais.rkn.gov.ru/

Comment: @edem Казахстан